# Curl equivalent of Invoke-RestMethod https://XXXX -CertificateThumbprint YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

Tags: powershell, curl

In a specific context, I need to perform a bunch of gets in the following manner:

```
Invoke-RestMethod https://XXXX -CertificateThumbprint YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

This works perfectly fine on Windows. Now I would like to do the same on linux but can't figure out the curl (or other tool) equivalent.

Can someone point to me the curl (or other tool) equivalent of the above powershell command?

**---(Added following comments)---**

Here is the documentation for [-CertificateThumbprint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.3#-certificatethumbprint). Here are some key elements to keep in mind:

- [-CertificateThumbprint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.3#-certificatethumbprint) will use client certificate-based authentication for you request.
- Here is a nice link describing [client certificate-based authentication](https://www.yubico.com/resources/glossary/what-is-certificate-based-authentication/#:%7E:text=Certificate%2DBased%20Authentication%20Definition&text=Generally%20speaking%2C%20client%20certificate%2Dbased,a%20network%20or%20other%20resources.)
- As per doc. This feature is currently only supported on Windows OS platforms.

  - *Even if this is only supported by Windows. There must be a way to perform the equivalent with other means...*

I suspect [-CertificateThumbprint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.3#-certificatethumbprint) might use the private key in the background.

Comment: What does the `-CertificateThumbprint` option do?

Comment: You are just making an HTTPS (secure with certifcate).  See following : https://www.baeldung.com/linux/curl-https-connection?force_isolation=true

Comment: @tripleee : Read the Invoke-RestMethod documentation.  It is just the certificate that is used for TLS.

Comment: @tripleee It allows client certificate-based authentication as described in client certificate-based authentication

Comment: Do note that the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.3#-certificatethumbprint) says: "This feature is currently only supported on Windows OS platforms.", but that could be the reason why you need the curl-variant of this....

Comment: @jdweng just tried the example from your reference. Currently I can't get it to work

Comment: Is it possible windows use private key in the background here and that my curl equivalent should be:
curl -v -GET --key key.pem --cert cert.pem https://example.com

Example taken from (https://www.misterpki.com/curl-authentication/)

Comment: Are you getting a response?  What is status code.  TLS (HTTPS) is sent before a request is sent.  If TLS fails than request is not sent and no response.  So if you are not getting a response than it probably means the certificate being used is not loaded in both client and server.  TLS the server sends a certificate block with names of possible certificates.  Then client looks up in stores the certificate names to find matching certificate.  The certificate is not sent, only the names are sent.

Comment: @jdweng If I use curl with --cert and use the same cert as the one from my powershell cmd thumbprint. I am redirected to a place that basically tells me I am unauthorized.

Comment: Does it work with any other tools with linux?  Did you try Putty?  Is liux machine configured to use HTTPS (not HTTP)?  What port number is being used 8080 or 80?  I would try getting it working with Putty or Postman before trying with PS.

Comment: @jdweng I can't test putty for now. With Postman I can't since I have only access to crt file. If I look into https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/#managing-certificates I also need a key file (*.key), a pfx file (*.pfx) and a passphrase. Maybe  Invoke-RestMethod https://XXXX -CertificateThumbprint manages additional files in the background and allows the user to simply use the cert thumbprint.

Comment: The key is inside a certificate. You need a key file only when creating the certificate.  You do not need a second key.  Just certificate.

Comment: Postman is more robust than PS.  Postmen will set a lot of options that aren't automatically added to PS.  So it is easier to get Postman working.  Once Postmen works than you can attempt to try PS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A certificate thumbprint is neither a certificate nor a private key. It is a checksum/hash of a certificate to make it easier to identify.

When you pass a `-CertificateThumbprint` to `Invoke-RestMethod`, it will look up that certificate in your Windows certificate store. To be able to use that certificate for mutual TLS, you also need a private key associated to that certificate. As you can use your certificate successfully with `Invoke-RestMethod`, I assume you also own the corresponding private key.

Of course you need a private key for mutual TLS. You need the private key to be able to prove you are the owner of the certificate that you present to the server. But you do not have to and even must not send your private key to the server.

As you already mentioned in the comments, you have to pass the private key to `curl`. It will use it for mutual TLS, but it will not send it to the server. Example:

```
curl --cert client.crt --key client.key https://domain.tld
```

If you need to export your certificate and private key from Windows to use it on Linux, you may have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73024898/11942268).

Comment: Thx, unfortunately I am in a context where I don't have access to the private key therefore I can't test your answer and must stay with Powershell. I assume Invoke-RestMethod with -CertificateThumbprint must handle the private key behind the scene since the request is working without an explicit reference to the private key.

Comment: Yes, with the thumbrint, the certificate will be looked up in your Windows certificate store. And the certificate store also has a reference to the private key, if there is one. That's how `Invoke-RestMethod` finds both, the certificate and the private key, when you provide the certificate thumbprint.